# why does the answer come out negative

Tags: java, cycle

the number entered by the user is 100000
after execution, it outputs a negative answer-72900
I have do the cycle there.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        //введите код сюда
        do {
            long x = (amount / 10) - amount;
            long y = (x / 10) - x;
            long z = (y / 10) - y;
   
            System.out.println(z);
        } while(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have `do ... while (false)`?

Comment: Try the calculation on a calculator. -17,900 is correct. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

`q/10 - q` is (approximately, because you're actually using integer arithmetic) `-0.9 * q` for any `q`.

The sign therefore changes on each step

Simple arithmetic, not a programming issue.

You didn't state what you were trying to do, so it's difficult to correct your code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer displayed is correct based on simple arithmetic calculation.

Moreover, even if you use `do ... while (true)` you will always get same answer -72900 because you have declared `x,y,z` as variables local to `do..while` loop & the way you are doing calculation i.e. initializing `x` to
`(amount / 10) - amount`

Comment: As `x` is always set to `(amount / 10) - amount` at the start of each iteration, that will make no difference.

Comment: oh yeah, correct, updating my suggestion.

Comment: `System.out.println(z)` is inside do while, so I think it will at least print `z`; so giving answer i mean printing value of z

Comment: You're correct.